# Android code for showing List View of JSON

Tags: android, json, listview

How can I code java to show JSON data from `"http://services.groupkt.com/country/search?text=un"`? I want to see list view of data.

Trying below doesn't seem to work:

```
private String loadJSON(String jsonURL) throws IOException {

    URL url = new URL(jsonURL);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.connect();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

        response.append(line);
    }

    in.close();
    return response.toString();
}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors or anything in return? However, why don't you use GSON which is simpler to use and easy to get the values? That sounds like a old approach.

Comment: no errors. just white screen with banner along top of app

Answer (score 0):

Working class example:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class JsonReader {

  private static String readAll(Reader rd) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int cp;
    while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
      sb.append((char) cp);
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }

  public static JSONObject readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {
    InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
    try {
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
      String jsonText = readAll(rd);
      JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);
      return json;
    } finally {
      is.close();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JSONException {
    JSONObject json = readJsonFromUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/19292868552");
    System.out.println(json.toString());
    System.out.println(json.get("id"));
  }
}
```